# replace consecutive spaces with one comma using command line

Tags: linux, string, awk

Wondering the most efficient solution to replace one or more consecutive spaces with one comma? A single command is preferred. :)

I am using Mac OS/Linux.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this one-liner a try, this will not replace the spaces at the BOL or EOL

```
awk -v OFS="," '{$1=$1}7' file
```

this line will replace all spaces:

```
awk '1+gsub(/ +/,",")' file
```

another one with sed, this will replace all spaces, including leading and ending ones

```
sed 's/ \+/,/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `tr` provides out of the box

```
tr -s ' ' ','
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/  */,/g'
```

As an example:

```
$ echo 'a b  c   d' | sed 's/  */,/g'
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Noting the comment about leading/trailing spaces for this example (and suggesting that OP might not want to convert *those*):

```
sed 's/ \+/,/g' file
```

and that most people would consider <kbd>TAB</kbd> a "space", one could use a more comprehensive (but complicated) approach:

```
sed \
    -e ':loop' \
    -e 's/\([^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]\)/\1,\2/g' \
    -e 't loop' file
```

The loop is needed to handle the case where the `\1` and `\2` overlap.

Here is an example input:

```
total 36
drwx------ 5 root root  4096 Aug 21 03:58 0994576031
drwx------ 4 tom  users 4096 Aug 21 04:27 fake-tom
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom  users    0 Aug 21 04:53 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom  users  155 Aug 21 04:27 gpgagent.log
drwx------ 2 tom  users 4096 Aug 21 04:27 gpg-MOxBtc
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 Aug 21 03:58 kde-root
drwx------ 2 tom  users 4096 Aug 21 04:27 ssh-cdcgKy3228
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root  4096 Aug 21 03:57 VMwareDnD
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 21 03:58 vmware-root
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 Aug 21 03:58 vmware-root-2999462734
```

and output

```
total,36
drwx------,5,root,root,4096,Aug,21,03:58,0994576031
drwx------,4,tom,users,4096,Aug,21,04:27,fake-tom
-rw-r--r--,1,tom,users,0,Aug,21,04:53,foo
-rw-r--r--,1,tom,users,155,Aug,21,04:27,gpgagent.log
drwx------,2,tom,users,4096,Aug,21,04:27,gpg-MOxBtc
drwx------,2,root,root,4096,Aug,21,03:58,kde-root
drwx------,2,tom,users,4096,Aug,21,04:27,ssh-cdcgKy3228
drwxrwxrwt,2,root,root,4096,Aug,21,03:57,VMwareDnD
drwxr-xr-x,2,root,root,4096,Aug,21,03:58,vmware-root
drwx------,2,root,root,4096,Aug,21,03:58,vmware-root-2999462734
```